# Finding the actual weights in the optimal solution to the knapsack problem by modifying given code

Tags: knapsack-problem

Given a set of n weights and their n corresponding values find the number of times each of these weights occurs in a given collection of weights such that the total weight of the collection does not exceed W, and the total value of the collection, which is the sum of the values of the weights in the collection, is maximized.

I have written Python code to output the value of the optimal collection given W, but I was unable to output the constituent weights in the optimal collection. Can someone modify the code I have written to output the constituent weights in the optimal collection? I tried to return the weight l[i][1] corresponding to the max(m) but that does not work because this weight is picked up for all nodes in the recursion not all of which constitute a part of the final solution.

```
def ks(w, l):
   mini=min([l[i][0] for i in range(len(l))])
   if w<mini:
    return 0

   m=[l[i][1]+ks(w-l[i][0],l) for i in range(len(l)) if w-l[i][0]>=0]    
   return max(m)    

print(ks(15,[[2,4],[3,3],[5,2]]))
```

In the invocation of ks above, W=15, and there are three weights - weight 2 with value 4, weight 3 with value 3, and weight 5 with value 2.
So the input is 15,[[2,4],[3,3],[5,2]]

The answer is 28 because a collection of weights comprising the weight 2 taken 7 times comes closest to 15 without exceeding 15, and also has the highest possible value of 4 * 7 = 28.

I also want to print the actual weights in the optimal collection -  2,2,2,2,2,2,2.